# change class depend on string values

Tags: vue.js

I need to change div class depend on variable value. The problem that value can have multiples values that should be evaluated as true for me.

```
isActive: "yes"
```

can be: "true", "agree". How to add switch of class and accept all this three variants: "yes", "true", "agree"?

https://jsfiddle.net/ogx1pt3y/

Answer (score 1):

You can have a computed property where you return the correct class based on many conditions:

```
<p :class="paragraphClasses">{{ message }}</p>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    isActive: 'yes',
    shouldBeRed: true
  },
  computed: {
    paragraphClasses() {
      return this.isActive == 'yes' && this.shouldBeRed ? 'big' : 'small';
    }
  }
})
```